# Comparing to dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have a *function* that takes a string that counts the individual characters and puts the character along with the amount of time it shows up into a string. E.g:

```
isanagram("surfer")
```

returns

```
w1 = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 2, 's': 1, 't': 0, 'u': 1, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Although when I compare this function with two different parameters the print statement outputs *True* instead of *False*, which it clearly should be. Could anyone take a look. Here is my code:

```
alphabetlist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    alphabetdict = {}
    newalphadict = {}    
              
    def isanagram(aword):
        for i in alphabetlist:
            count = word.count(i) 
            alphabetdict[i] = count
            
        return alphabetdict
    
     print(isanagram("computer") == isanagram("science")) #outputting True. Should be outputting False.
```

Comment: `isanagram()` takes `aword` as argument, but in the function you use `word`

Comment: You're constantly adding to the same single dictionary object...

Comment: aside: python has a Counter object: `from collections import Counter; c = Counter("computer")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alphabetlist = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
        
def isanagram(word=''):
    alphabetdict = {}
    for i in alphabetlist:
        count = word.count(i) 
        alphabetdict[i] = count
    
    return alphabetdict

print(isanagram("computer") == isanagram("science")) #-> False
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code.  Here is a better version:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_anagram(word1, word2):    

    c1 = Counter(word1)
    c2 = Counter(word2)
    return c1 == c2

is_anagram("computer", "science") # False
```

This solves the following issues with your current code:

- `newalphadict`, `alphabetdict` reside outside your function, so letters get added to them every time `isanagram` is called (a bug)
- `is_anagram` compares two words. It should probably take two words as arguments (and nothing else).
- `aword` != `word`
- you don't have to pre-populate the dictionary.  You could do this with a bit of try/accept logic and a dict, or use a defaultdict, but Counter already exists so lets use it.

Comment: Why is there a cast to `bool()`? `c1 == c2` already returns a boolean.

Comment: for clarity, not required

Comment: I think it reduces clarity. I look at that and imagine `Counter` must be doing something wonky with `__eq__` somehow.